# Django ugettext_lazy, interpolation and ChoiceField

Tags: django, internationalization

I want a ChoiceField with these choices:

```
choices = [(1, '1 thing'),
           (2, '2 things'),
           (3, '3 things'),
           ...]
```

and I want to have it translated.

This does not work:

```
choices = [(i, ungettext_lazy('%s thing', '%s things', i) % i) for i in range(1,4)]
```

because as soon as the lazy object is interpolated, it becomes a unicode object - since ChoiceField.choices is evaluated at startup, its choices will be in the language active during Django's startup.

I could use `ugettext_lazy('%s things' % i)`, but that would require a translation for each numeral, which is silly. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: By "the lazy object is interpolated", do you mean "the expression `(i, ungettext_lazy('%s thing', '%s things', i) % i) for i in range(1,4)` is evaluated, and a list and a list generated from it"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Django documentation, [*Translation*… *Working with lazy translation objects*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#working-with-lazy-translation-objects), I see a remark which seems to address your concern here.

> Using [`ugettext_lazy()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy) and [`ungettext_lazy()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.ungettext_lazy) to mark strings in models and utility functions is a common operation. When you're working with these objects elsewhere in your code, you should ensure that you don't accidentally convert them to strings, because they should be converted as late as possible (so that the correct locale is in effect). This necessitates the use of the helper function described next.

Then they present `django.utils.functional.lazy(func, *resultclasses)`, which is not presently covered by the [`django.utils.functional` module documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.functional). However, according to the [`django.utils.functional.py` source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/functional.py), it "Turns any callable into a lazy evaluated callable.… the
function is evaluated on every access."

Modifying their [example from *Other uses of lazy in delayed translations*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#other-uses-of-lazy-in-delayed-translations) to incorporate your code, the following code might work for you.

```
from django.utils import six  # Python 3 compatibility
from django.utils.functional import lazy
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

choices = [
    (i, lazy(
        mark_safe(ungettext_lazy('%s thing', '%s things', i) % i),
        six.text_type
    )# lazy()
    for i in range(1,4)
]
```

Also, the [`django.utils.functional` module documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.functional) does mention a function decorator `allow_lazy(func, *resultclasses)`. This lets you write your own function which takes a lazy string as arguments. "It modifies the function so that if it's called with a lazy translation as the first argument, the function evaluation is delayed until it needs to be converted to a string."  `lazy(func, *resultclasses)` is not a decorator, it modifies a callable.

N.B. I haven't tried this code in Django. I'm just passing along what I found in the documentation. Hopefully it will point you to something you can use.

Comment: Not knowing about functional.lazy, I ended up defining my own "lazy" class by overriding `__mod__` and `__unicode__`, but I think this is how you are supposed to do it - and what I was asking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For those who encounter this question. Unfortunately, @Jim DeLaHunt's answer doesn't completely work - it's almost there, but not exactly what needs to be done.

The important distinctions are:

1. What you need to warp with `lazy` is a function that'd return you a text value, not another lazy translation object, or you'll likely see weird `<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at ...>` instead of the actual text (IIRC Django won't go deep down the chain of lazy objects). So, use `ungettext`, not `ungettext_lazy`.
2. You want to do string interpolation only when the wrapped function runs. If you write `lazy(f("%d" % 42))` the interpolation would happen too early - in this case Python evaluates eagerly. And don't forget about variable scopes - you can't just refer to the iterator from the wrapped function.

Here, I've used a `lambda` that receives a number argument and does the interpolation. The code inside `lambda` is only executed when lazy object is evaluated, that is, when the choice is rendered.

So, the working code is:

```
choices = [
    (
        (i, lazy(
            lambda cnt: ungettext(u"%(count)d thing",
                                  u"%(count)d things", cnt)
                        % {"count": cnt},
            six.text_type
        )(i))
    )
    for i in [1, 2, 3]
]
```

This will correctly have the same intended effect as

```
choices = [
    (1, _("1 thing")),
    (2, _("2 things")),
    (3, _("3 things")),
]
```

But there will be just a single entry for this in translation database, not multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a situation where you could benefit from the trick taught by  Ilian Iliev's blog, [*Django forms ChoiceField with dynamic values…*](http://ilian.i-n-i.org/django-forms-choicefield-with-dynamic-values/).

Iliev shows a very similar initialiser:

```
my_choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_my_choices())
```

He says, "the trick is that in this case my_choice_field choices are initialized on server (re)start. Or in other words once you run the server the choices are loaded(calculated) and they will not change until next (re)start."  Sounds like the same difficulty you are encountering.

His trick is: "fortunately the form`s class has an **init** method that is called on every form load. Most of the times you skipped it in the form definition but now you will have to use it."

Here is his sample code, blended with your generator expression:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_choice_field'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=(
                (i, ungettext_lazy('%s thing', '%s things', i) % i) 
                for i in range(1,4)
            )# choices=
    )# __init__
```

The generator expression is enclosed in parentheses so that it is treated as a generator object, which is assigned to `choices`.

N.B. I haven't tried this code in Django. I'm just passing along Iliev's idea.